# Unable to trigger an evt when clicking on a specific button

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, datatables, target

I have three plus (+) buttons next to three separate tables (built with DataTables). Since the +s were created in one location (with DT), clicking on any of them opens the same modal. For the most part, they have the same DOM structure and classes.

I want to make it so that clicking on one of the +s does one thing, clicking on the second + does another thing, etc. There are slight differences in some of the IDs of the parents and I'm trying to use specificity to target specific +s.

I'm writing because I've been unable to target only one + (console.log's not working).

It's probably something pretty silly, but I've been tinkering with this and haven't had any luck, so I wanted to ask about it here.

#### JS snippet:

```
// $(document).on("click", ".btn-new", disp._newRole); // ----- this works, but it triggers every +

$(document).on("click", "#DataTables_Table_2_wrapper > .btn-group > .btn-default > .btn-new", disp._newRole);

$(document).on("click", "#DataTables_Table_2_wrapper > .btn-group > .btn-default > .btn-new", function() {
    console.log('hello')
});
```

#### Screencap:

`#DataTables_Table_2_wrapper` is unique. The two other tables use a 0 and 1 instead of a 2.

[image]

#### JS (where the + is created)

```
buttons: [
                {
                  text:      '<div class="btn btn-new" style="bottom:0.75rem; padding-right:2rem; position:relative;" title="Click to add new search"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div>',
                  titleAttr: 'Add',
                  exportOptions: {
                      columns: _colExport
                  }
                },
```

Comment: Please provide snippet for HTML code

Comment: Would be very nice to provide html as code, not as image

Comment: @Rishab Just added it

Comment: No, you have to add rendered html, which was provided on the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss a child in the target `.btn-new`

```
$(document).on("click", "#DataTables_Table_2_wrapper > .btn-group > .btn-default > span > .btn-new > .fa-plus", function() {
console.log('hello')});
```

And i suggest you to declare a custom class and avoid too nested targets, as it can easily generates errors and decreases code readability.

Comment: Hey @andrea-facchini, thanks for the info. but unfortunately the event wasn't triggered. `$(document).on("click", ".btn-new", disp._newRole);` this still works (just tested it), so I'm not sure why the other two lines aren't working.

Comment: @Bodrov i edit my answer, i was missing a span element

Comment: @andrea-facchnini that did it, thanks! I'll definitely incorporate a custom class to make things easier to read (and work with).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to simplify your selector by using [:first-of-type](https://api.jquery.com/first-of-type-selector/) selector or without it if you are sure that your wrapper contains only 1 element with your condition. Here I've prepared a sample example.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#a1 .your-class:first-of-type', function(){
 console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a1">
 <div>
  <i class='your-class'>1</i>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="a2">
<div>
  <i class='your-class'>2</i>
 </div>
</div>
```

If you will not be able to adapt this to your current code, I will help you with it.